# Matlab: How to calculate return for every stock

Tags: matlab, stock

tr9sh, thanks for editing the question, but I have to clarify I didn't ask for calculating daily return. What I want is to calculate annual return by locating the row of the date without enter the data 'price' . The formula would look like this: (price(2001/1/20)/price(2000/1/21) - 1)

The closing price for 'n stocks in n period' is imported into Matlab like this:

2000/1/1  23.4  78.9 ...

2000/1/2  23.3  67.1 ...

...

2001/1/1 23.2 77.1 ...

2001/1/2 24.1 78.1 ...

The number in each column is the price for each stock. If I want to calculate the annual return  for each of them, how should my code look?

I have tried

```
Return = (filename(find(2001/1/1)),2)/(filename(find(2000/1/1)),2) - 1
```

Comment: Are you saying that the data is in the form of a text file, with spaces between each entry?

Comment: sorry I didn't write it clear..there are no spaces..and it is in mat. format

Comment: You need to be more clear. What is the result if you type `load filename` into MATLAB (where `filename`) is the name of the .mat file?

Comment: Yes, it is the .mat file. The first column is the date and the '2nd to n' column are the prices for (n-2) different stocks

Comment: What is the result if you type `load filename`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite know what you want, but the following solution may work for you. Say your data is stored in the matrix `X`. Then

```
close = X(:,2:end);
ret   = close(2:end,:) ./ close(1:end-1,:) - 1;
dates = X(2:end,1);
```

Comment: Cool. Now if I could get you to do me (and yourself) a favour - sit down and make sure you *understand* why this piece of code works for you. It'll be better in the long run!

Comment: The code didn't solve my problem directly but it does help me understand and get the work done. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

you're trying to use 'find' for a string. Next time try regexp ( http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/regexp.html and http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/regexpi.html for the case insensitive variant)

but I would do it differently: read each line and extract the date and prices.
When that's done: search the dates (stored in an seperate array, as numbers, not as chars) for year/month and at last day. Use the found index to get the corresponding prices out of the price array

btw, you say it's stored in a mat file? but you're example more looks like a text file??
For a text file it's easiest to use the scanf ( http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html) function to get your data

Comment: It is mat file, yes the dates are stored as numbers...the first column is the date and the second to n column are the prices for (n-2) different stocks. Do I have to use a loop run the calculation for each stocks' return, or is there a formula for it? Thanks!!